# NDepend CQL Count Query

Tags: aggregate, cql, ndepend

I want to query a table of public methods of a specific class and a count of each methods usage in NDepend CQL. Currently query looks like this:

```
SELECT METHODS 
FROM TYPES "AE.DataAccess.DBHelper" 
WHERE IsPublic
```

Is it possible to aggregate queries in CQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following query will generate a nice table with the values I was looking for that can be exported to Excel. What an awesome tool.

> SELECT METHODS FROM TYPES
>   "AE.DataAccess.DBHelper" WHERE
>   IsPublic ORDER BY MethodCa DESC

Comment: would be nice to have aggregate queries... but I don't see it on the specs: http://www.ndepend.com/CQL.htm